# Malformed URL after deleting row with SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite

I wrote a script that can open tabs in the TOR browser with a for loop. I used a database as the list the loop had to go through and one of the last links gave the error : invalid URL (the other URLS still worked. I deleted the row from my database but now the whole loop does not work and I don't know how to fix this. Can someone help me?

```
enter code here

create_table()\
onion()\
zoekterm = input()\
url_list = []\
url_list.append(cursor.execute("SELECT URL FROM dark_web").fetchall())\
url_list1 = url_list[0]\
count = 0

for url in url_list1:\
    print(url[0]) \
    driver.get(url[0])\
    timeout=60
    print("URL bezocht")\
    count += 1
```

I am connected to TOR through Selenium and my databases are imported.

Error: selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: Malformed URL: URL constructor: Leaktheanalyst.fireeye62c3da3fnosymmmcqcty7rl7cjucpbkzaz275a4qs5fgkzhad.onion is not a valid URL.

Comment: Where is the code that does the deletion? All we see is just selecting URLs from a table. And you cllaim that you start with all valid URLs? As an aside: Why do you append a list of rows to an empty list and then extract out that list? In other words, why not just `url_list1 = cursor.execute("SELECT URL FROM dark_web").fetchall()`?

Comment: I deleted the row within the database and not in Python (maybe that's the problem?). I checked all the URLS before I put them in the database. Thanks for the tip! Still very new to programming so I have a lot to learn :)

Comment: Perhaps `timeout=60` should be _inside_ the parentheses in the previous line?  So `driver.get(url[0], timeout=60)`?  Also you don't need the `\` at the end of each line unless you are breaking a single logical line over two physical lines.